# Capturing the newly created node with JSTree contextmenu

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, contextmenu, jstree

I'm trying to capture the name of the newly created node with jstree's contextmenu.  I can capture the name of the parent node that I'm adding the new node under (with obj.text()), however, what I really need is the name of the newly created node.

So, somehow, there needs to be an "onChange" event that can be called within jstree contextmenu that fires once the user hits enter on that newly created node?

Any ideas?  I've enclosed the contextmenu code:

```
}).jstree({
        json_data: {
            data: RBSTreeModel,
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: function (n) {
                    return {
                        NodeID: n.attr("id").substring(4),
                        Level: n.attr("name").substring(7)
                    };
                },
                url: function (node) {
                    return "/Audit/GetRequirementsTreeStructure";
                },
                success: function (new_data) {
                    return new_data;
                }
            }
        },
        contextmenu: {
            items: function($node) {
                return {
                    createItem : {
                        "label" : "Create New Branch",
                        "action" : function(obj) { this.create(obj); alert(obj.text())},
                        "_class" : "class"
                    },
                    renameItem : {
                        "label" : "Rename Branch",
                        "action" : function(obj) { this.rename(obj);}
                    },
                    deleteItem : {
                        "label" : "Remove Branch",
                        "action" : function(obj) { this.remove(obj); }
                    }
                };
            }
        },
        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu"]
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind to the "create.jstree" event, which will fire after a node is created.  In the callback of that event, you will have access to the newly created node and can rollback/revert the create node action if you choose.  The documentation for it is lacking, but there is an example on the [demo page](http://www.jstree.com/demo).  Here is another example that came from my code:

```
}).jstree({... You jstree setup code...})
        .bind("create.jstree", function(e, data) {
            // use your dev tools to examine the data object
            // It is packed with lots of useful info
            // data.rslt is your new node
            if (data.rslt.parent == -1) {
                alert("Can not create new root directory");
                // Rollback/delete the newly created node
                $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                return;
            }
            if (!FileNameIsValid(data.rslt.name)) {
                alert("Invalid file name");
                // Rollback/delete the newly created node
                $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                return;
            }
            .. Your code etc...
        })
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. The jstree documentation has areas for improvent.

Comment: @Bojin Li rollback() api seem to be missing in latest jstree version. Can you suggest an alternative for rollback?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Bojin Li's answer, it seems that the latest version of jsTree uses the event "create_node" instead of "create":

```
}).jstree({... You jstree setup code...})
      .bind("create_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
        ...
       });
```

Comment: It's strange, when I try to bind to the create_node.jstree event, it fires before the new node is actually created, so the text I get is always "New Node", instead of whatever name the user wants to give it... Do you know how to capture the newly created node after it's been created?

Comment: I think you have to use rename_node.jstree as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733744/jstree-get-new-node-after-node-is-created)