# jsTree Get new node AFTER node is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am attempting to obtain the text value of the newly created node AFTER the user edits the name of the new node and presses Enter.

When I do this:

```
        .on('create_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var id = data.node.id;
            alert($('#' + id).text());
        });
```

All I get is "New Node" in my alert. I have been scouring this site for an answer as well as perusing the API documentation on the jstree website for some time, But they provide few examples, so as a jQuery novice, it is pretty difficult for me to understand.

So, my question is which event do I actually need to program against to be able to obtain the ID of the node that was just created? is it the `changed.jstree` event? If so, how do I utilize this?

**EDIT**
Might help to mention I am attempting this through a context menu; Here is how I have my "create" item set up:

```
                items = {
                    "create": {
                        "label": "New Category",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            $node = tree.create_node(node);
                            tree.edit($node);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event you might be looking for is `rename_node.jstree`. It would look like:

```
.on('rename_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
  //data.text is the new name:
  alert(data.text);
});
```

Comment: Still, all that does is alert "New Node". I need to figure out what event (if any) actually fires once the user types in a new name for the node and presses Enter.

Comment: @takiMartillo I get it now, sorry. I'll get back to you in a sec.

Comment: @takiMartillo I edited the answer. Hopefully it answers the question now :)

Comment: heh I'm a doofus. I don't know why I didn't see the "rename.jstree" event, I guess I've just been staring at this screen too long. What's funny is I was like two seconds away from doing that. 

I WISH there were some more thorough documentation on what exactly is contained in the data parameter, because nine times out of ten I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @takiMartillo the docs are unclear, but they actually do explain what is in the data parameter. In the rename node explanation https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=rename_node.jstree , it lists three things: `node`, `text`, and `old`. That means the callback for `rename_node` will have `data.node, data.text`, and `data.old`.

Comment: AHHH so THAT's what those thingies are. Here, I thought to myself "are those...the... parameters...?" ... I now see they are attributes of the data object, thank you, thank you very much. You've made the world a little less dumb today.

Comment: No problem, I thought the docs were very confusing, I only figured that out by reading __your__ code in the question, where you use `data.node.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84747/discussion-between-taki-martillo-and-sam-h).

Comment: @takiMartillo, @sam H. I realize this is a long shot since it's been nearly 3 years but.... could one of you perhaps show how the `.on('rename_node')` fits in with the node creation. I can not for the life of me figure out how they go together.

Comment: OP said "I am attempting to obtain the text value of the newly created node AFTER the user edits the name of the new node and presses Enter" - and so, the node is being renamed.